# How to disable my wordpress page from scrolling up when clicking inside an iFrame?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, elementor

Recently I added an iFrame using the following code I found online:

"<iframe id=“personio-iframe” style=“border: none;” src=“my website address is here” width=“100%”  onload=“window.top.scrollTo(0,0);“>  window.addEventListener(‘message’, function(e) {    var iframe = document.querySelector(‘#personio-iframe’);    var eventName = e.data[0];    var data = e.data[1];    switch(eventName) {      case ‘setHeight’:        iframe.style.height = data + ‘px’;        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: ‘smooth’ });        break;    }  }, false);"

I noticed whenever I click on any part inside an iFrame the page scrolls up.

I can see the two lines in the code that mention scrolling up, but when I tried to delete them the frame doesn't show properly, it's displayed as a narrow bar on the page.

Can you please let me know how can I modify this code to successfully get rid of the scrolling up without damaging the iFrame itself?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this line:

```
<iframe id="personio-iframe" style="border: none;" src="your website address is here" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

This is optional for your css, with it the iframe will not go over 90% of screen height

```
#personio-iframe {max-height:90vh;}
```

Comment: Thank you Petros! It actually helped with the scrolling problem I had, but now the content around the iFrame doesn't show in the preview of the page anymore, it just disappears and displays the empty space instead. Do you have any idea what can cause that? Do I need to add something else to the code?

Comment: The iframe closing tag was missing from my code </iframe>, i have edited the answer. I forgot it sorry.